# Prolog take a part of a list

Tags: prolog

How can I take a part of a list?
example :

```
?- part([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],3,6,Χ).
X = [3,4,5,6]
```

The first element should be the start and the second should be the end.

Comment: and this is by index, or by value?

Comment: @WillNess and OP: and if by value, what do we know about the values? Are they unique? Are they of some type? Is the list ground?

Comment: @TA_intern as you can see, some answers treat them as indices, and some -- as values.  One answer allows for multiple solutions, and another  does not. :)

Answer (score 4):

This answer obviously takes the second and third arguments as indexes. But maybe they are meant to be values? This brings up a whole lot of other questions since indexes are unique, ordered and so on, while values can be just about anything.

This has been solved many times in different ways. Surely many solutions for this on Stackoverflow. One way is to use length/2 and append/3 twice:

```
?- List = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
   length(Skip, 2), append(Skip, Rest, List),
   length(Take, 4), append(Take, _, Rest).
Take = [3, 4, 5, 6].
```

You need to calculate the two lengths from the indices:

```
?- From = 3, To = 6,
   N_skip is From - 1,
   N_take is To - From + 1.
N_skip = 2,
N_take = 4.
```

The other way to do it is to count it down yourself, and that can be written in many different ways.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that the list has duplicate elements, a possible solution is:

```
part(List, Begin, End, Part) :-
    append(_, [Begin|Rest], List),         % suffix starting with Begin
    append(Prefix, [End|_], [Begin|Rest]), % prefix of the suffix ending just before End
    append(Prefix, [End], Part).
```

Here are some examples:

```
?- part([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],3,6,P).
P = [3, 4, 5, 6] ;
false.

?- part([10,11,12,13,1,4,1,5,16],13,16,P).
P = [13, 1, 4, 1, 5, 16] ;
false.

?- part([1,2,3],2,E,P).
E = 2,
P = [2] ;
E = 3,
P = [2, 3] ;
false.

?- part([1,2,3,4,5,3,6,7,8,6,9],3,6,P).
P = [3, 4, 5, 3, 6] ;
P = [3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 6] ;
P = [3, 6] ;
P = [3, 6, 7, 8, 6] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

**1-** `split predicate` takes the list [H|T], Start (Starting Number), Last (Last Number), and NewList.

**2-** `s1 predicate` takes the Last Number and generates a whole List till the last number. Example: if 6 is the given last number from the List =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], then s1 will give List=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

**3-** `s2 predicate` will take the generated list from s1 ([1,2,3,4,5,6]), and using the Starting number (3) will discard all previous numbers and give us the remaining list. Example: s1 gives [1,2,3,4,5,6], s2 using start number 3 gives [3,4,5,6].

```
split([H|T],Start,Last,NewList):-
    s1([H|T],Last,N1),
    s2(N1,Start,NewList).

s1([H|T],LastN,[H|L]):-
    H\=LastN,
    s1(T,LastN,L).
s1([H|_],LastN,[LastN]):-
    H=LastN,!.

s2([H|T],StartN,[H|T]):-
    H=StartN.
s2([H|T],StartN,L):-
    H\=StartN,
    s2(T,StartN,L).
```

**Example:**

```
?- split([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],3,6,L).
L = [3, 4, 5, 6]
false

?- split([10,11,12,13,1,4,1,5,16],13,16,L).
L = [13, 1, 4, 1, 5, 16]
false
```

Comment: `split([1,2],2,E,R).` fails, but `E = 2, split([1,2],2,E,R).` succeeds. Either produce an instantiation error, or succeed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If your Prolog has dif/2, you can generalize the snippet in this way

```erlang
take_el_start_stop(L,X,Y,R) :-
    phrase(take_el_start_stop(X,Y,R),L,_).

take_el_start_stop(X,Y,[X|R]) -->
    [X], take_el_to_stop(Y,R).
take_el_start_stop(X,Y,R) -->
    [Z], {dif(X,Z)}, take_el_start_stop(X,Y,R).

take_el_to_stop(Y,[Y]) --> [Y].
take_el_to_stop(Y,[Z|R]) -->
    [Z],
    % {dif(Y,Z)}, uncomment for a strict start/stop match
    take_el_to_stop(Y,R).
```

*edit*

Didn't noticed the ambiguity in your question. Indeed, instead of values, the start and stop elements could be 1-based indexes as well. In that case, nth1/3 with findall/3 would work:

```erlang
get_elems_between_start_and_stop(L,Start,Stop,R) :-
  findall(E,(between(Start,Stop,I),nth1(I,L,E)),R).
```

Comment: The query ```?- take_el_start_stop([1,2,3],2,E,P), E=2.``` fails and the query ```?- take_el_start_stop([1,2,3,4,5,3,6,7,8,6,9],3,6,P).``` retrieves only one of the possible answers.

Comment: @slago: I think it's correct that `?- take_el_start_stop([1,2,3],2,E,P), E=2.` fail. For the second, see the comment introduced with last edit...  should do...

Comment: I think that ```?- take_el_start_stop([1,2,3],2,E,P), E=2``` should produce  a slice of the original list that starts in element 2 and ends in element 2, that is, the list ```[2]``` (I'm not considering 2 as a 1-based index, but I think that the result for this case should be the same). With respect to  the query ```?- take_el_start_stop([1,2,3,4,5,3,6,7,8,6,9],3,6,P)``` there are four different slices starting with a element 3 and ending with a element 6, thus I think that ```fail``` should not be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your *start* and *end* are indices into the list, this will work (assuming zero-based indices, where `0` is the index of the 1st element in the list:

```
part( List, X, Y, Part) :-
    X >= 0,
    Y >= X,
    L is Y - X + 1,
    length( Pfx , X ),
    length( Part, L ),
    append( Pfx, Sfx, List ),
    append( Part, _, Sfx ).
```